# Переставить модераторскую кнопку в конец списка

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, дизайн, инструменты-модератора

Вот так видит действия над вопросом обычный пользователь с достаточной репутацией:

[image: не модератор]

а вот так - модератор:

[image: модератор]

Обращаю внимание на кнопки <kbd>снять защиту</kbd> и <kbd>мод</kbd>.

Я считаю, что модераторскую кнопку <kbd>мод</kbd> надо перенести в конец списка, поскольку:

- Так будет одинаковый порядок кнопок на сайтах, независимо от того, являешься ли ты там модератором или нет
- Кнопка <kbd>поделиться</kbd> должна быть первой, поскольку используется в наиболее быстром взаимодействии с вопорсом: нашёл нужный вопрос, быстро прокрутил вниз, скопировал ссылку, вставил туда, куда собирался. Очень неудобно, когда в этом сценарии надо задумываться над совершаемым действием. Тем более, она может называться по-разному (<kbd>поделиться</kbd> или <kbd>share</kbd>), а из-за её расположения на первом месте даже текст читать не надо.
- Модераторская кнопка по сути является расширением возможностей кнопки <kbd>защитить</kbd> (защита является одним из подпунктов), поэтому логично её разместить на том же месте.
- Из набора ссылок наиболее заметны первая и последняя. Исходя из того, что это важная кнопка для модератора, а первое место хочется сохранить для другой кнопки, логично поставить её последней, чтобы до неё было так же легко добраться.

Css-костыль для желающих попробовать (не меняя разметку, универсальный):

```
.post-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.post-menu > a,
.post-menu > button {
    margin-right: .5em;
}

.post-menu-container {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.post-menu-container > a {
    display: inline-block;
}

.post-moderator-link, .js-post-moderator-link, .js-mod-menu-button {
    order: 2;
}

.lsep:first-of-type {
    order: 1;
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что это надо постить не нашу мету.

Comment: @AK, я ж [tag:обсуждение] поставил - хотелось бы сначала мнение наших модераторов и пользователей услышать, а потом уже можно будет и на metaSE тащить.

Comment: С точки зрения интерфейса -- решение правильное, тут и думать нечего. Непонятно только почему об этом никто не подумал. Так что постите у них и просите поддержки у нас, чтобы мы там своими плюсиками подкрепили.

Comment: Теперь ваше основное быстрое взаимодействие с вопросом - это *показать временную шкалу* и *переместить комментарии в чат* )) делиться ссылками некогда будет. Но идея неплохая.

Comment: @Nofate, а как же ссылками на мету в пользователей кидаться?)) А для временной шкалы есть блок слева в случае наличия тревог или удалённых комментариев. К тому же, если полез за шкалой или комментариями, то тут надо вдумываться в вопрос, а в копировании ссылки именно быстрое - открыл, проскроллил, правый клик, клик, закрыл.

Comment: Кто эти восемь модераторов, проголосовавшие за?

Comment: @NickVolynkin больше интересно, кто этот один, проголосовавший "против". И скоро ли он будет забанен.

Comment: @alexolut это я, никогда.

Comment: @Qwertiy а зачем ромб в заголовке? Есть же метка.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ромб предполагал нечто такое: [meta-tag:это-существенно-только-для-модераторов-но-если-вы-любопытный-то-тоже-стоит-заглянуть]. Метка [инструменты-модератора] этого не отражает, поскольку есть вопросы, которые затрагивают инструменты модераторов, но видимы для всех пользователей сайта.

Comment: @Qwertiy на самом деле ромбик тоже не отражает, поскольку без ознакомления текста по приведенной ссылке - смотрится как частые  попытки участников на ruSO впихнуть в заголовок невпихуемое)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, со временем привыкнут :) Ну и ромб как знак модераторов большинству активных пользователей знаком.

Comment: @Qwertiy если вопрос относится к какой-то особенной категории, придумайте для нее метку. Незачем изобретать костыли, вы плохой пример подаете.

Comment: @Qwertiy улучшение UI для модераторов - это хорошо, но почти не затрагивает обычных пользователей. т.е. это надо обсуждать или на общей мете (если там это онтопик), или на UI/UX (если хочется получить фибдек от прошаренных UX-еров), или в чате (0770 или общем модераторском). А так - ну да, проголосовало 10 человек за, 2 - против. При этом кнопку видело 5 человек. Почему непонятные анонимы будут решать, где **у меня** в интерфейсе будет стоять кнопка? :)

Comment: @PashaPash они надеются что уж в следующий раз - точно изберут)

Comment: @PashaPash, за последние 2 недели у меня эта кнопка раза 3-4 слетала и приходилось переписывать стиль. Стабильность, однако...

Answer (score 10):

Лично мне, как одному из тех, кто эту кнопку видит и часто использует, удобнее, когда она стоит первой в списке. Потому что ее **не приходится искать**.

Мне важно, чтобы **она была первой**. А не "где-то в конце списка кнопок, может быть на первой строке, может быть на второй".

- Меня не напрягает, что важный элемент появляется первым на тех сайтах, на которых я модератор.
- Я чаще жму на нее, чем на "поделится".
- Нет, это не расширение кнопки "защитить".
- На вопросе и на ответе - разные кнопки. сейчас и там и там мод стоит первой, слева на первой строке. Если переставить - будет стоиять на второй строке в середине для вопроса, и на первой справа для ответа. Странно переставлять кнопку в разное место в зависимости от типа поста.
- До последней кнопки добираться неудобно из-за переноса кнопок на вторую строку.

Да, на вопросе пачка плюсов. Но это плюсы от людей людей, которые эту кнопку вообще вживую не видели. Мне кажется *несколько нелогичным* использовать мету с возможностью голосования всех участников для того, чтобы решить, куда переставить *мою кнопку*. Не двигайте мой сыр!

Answer (score 5):

Все это напоминает мне ситуацию, когда новичок приходит в проект и первым делом начинает рефакторить код.

Оставьте все как есть. Две сотни людей уже привыкли к такому интерфейсу, а вы хотите сделать им всем непривычно, чтобы вам стало возможно удобнее.

Лучше используйте клавиатуру. <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> открывает модераторское меню на вопросах и ответах.
Дальше можно выбрать нужную цифру и нажать Enter. Swift justice!

Comment: 1. Но новые-то постоянно выбираются. 2. Привыкли к разному порядку кнопок на разных сайтах? 3. Но нужно-то share. 4. У меня шоткаты не включены. 5. Аргументы кроме "все привыкли" есть? Судя по ответу, ты вообще пользуешься клавиатурой, а не ссылкой, поэтому тебе вообще неважно, где она расположена?

Comment: @Qwertiy, у него юзерскрипты (на встрече видел). А это, кстати, идея — написать для greasemonkey перемещалку кнопки, чтобы каждый раз не редактировать CSS.

Comment: @Arhad, во-первых, у меня хром, во-вторых, для кастомных css расширений тоже полно. По-моему, даже, править css проще, чем скрипт, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy, для хрома есть tampermonkey. Насчёт простоты правки CSS согласен.